# Yii::app()->user->id is not returning the empty result

Tags: php, yii

I've a problem, it might be a small one but I couldn't find the solution for this. Yii:app()->user->getId() or Yii:app()->user->id is not returning value. it just returning empty result. But I've set the id in my UserIdentity class.

in my UserIdentity class I've this,

```
public function getId()
{
   return $this->id;
}
```

I'm setting id in the autheticate() function. if i displayed there itself it's displaying the id, but not in getId() function. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Dhanendran Rajagopal.

Comment: Can you show us your setter function or piece of code?

Comment: It's very likely that you set the id in the `UserIdentity`, not the `user` component - which is actually absolutely fine. You should pass an authenticated `UserIdentity` to `Yii::app()->user->login()`. If you still get `null` as user id, that simply means, that your user is not logged in correctly.

Comment: `Yii:app()->user-isGuest` will show you if you have a logged in user.

Comment: @javijuol: $this->id = $user->user_id; this is the code which i'm using for stting the id.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl: when i try to pass the user identity to Yii::app()->user->login() i'm getting error "UserIdentity and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named 'login'"

Comment: @Dhanendran You should call first your UserIdentity model and then Yii::app()->user->login() which is a CWebUser instance, not an UserIdentity...
So, you probably should run something like:
$userIdentity = new UserIdentity($user,$pass);
Yii::app()->user->login($userIdentity);
Your output error seems like Yii::app()->user is a UserIdentity instance, and should be a CWebUser instance...

Comment: We definitely need more code to be able to help you. Show your UserIdentity and the actual code you use to login your user. I also wonder, why you didn't go with the default login code, that is auto-generated with every new Yii app through`yiic webapp create`.

Comment: Can you post your entire UserIdentity code?

Comment: `$this->id = $user->user_id;` this is how i'm assigning value to the id.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your getId() function like this!

```
public function getId(){
    return $this->getState('id');
}
```

This problem  begin when you set the user states in your Identity. You try to set state, and then get an attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the standard UserIdentity class, but in the standard one `id` is a private attribute and in Yii convention private attributes have `_` in front of them, so it would be like this:

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

Since it is private variable you can't access it with `Yii::app()->user->_id`. The `getId()` function is a magic function, when you run  `Yii::app()->user->id`, it sees there is no `id` attribute so looks for a function named `getId()` and runs it if it exists.

If you are using the standard class you need to change this as you stated in your comment below:

```
$this->_id = $user->user_id //underscore added before id
```

Comment: Can you post your whole UserIdentity class?

Comment: That is little bit complicated dude, Because my company wont encourage this. Sorry :( But i'm setting `id` as `$this->id = $user->user_id`

Comment: Well what is the variable name? You should see something like this declared at the top of the class: 
`private $_id;` or `private $id;` or `public $_id;` or `public $id;` Which one is it?

Comment: I tried `private $_id;`, `private $id` and `public $id` nothing works for me:(