# Yii file permission verify doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, yii, filter, permissions

I have a question about yii.

I have some videos and the view action is performed based on some privileges. Some videos may be hidden, just for some user categories or for all. I can handle this from yii filter or something, but the real problem is what happen if someone knows the video file path, i can't handle the permissions in this case.

My solution is ok, but I have one problem - when someone access direct a file I redirect it (from `htaccess`) to a page, when I verify the user permission based on it's id. When I try to access the file from url everything is ok, the permission filter works fine, but when I the file is called from the player something it's wrong. From what I saw, the `Yii::app()->user->id` is empty.

Any recommendation?

This is my `UserIdentity` class:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
private $_id;
/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=Utilizator::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    if($user===null)
    {
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    }
    else
    {
        if($user->password!==$user->encrypt($this->password))
        {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_id = $user->id; 
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}


public function getId()
{
    return $this->username;
}
}
```

Comment: we could help you if you'd share your code

Comment: please share the code, also check the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286410/yiiapp-user-id-is-not-returning-the-empty-result

Comment: Thanks for response, i added the UserIdentity class if this helps. When I try to get the user's id I get it like this 'Yii::app()->user->getId()' and i print it in a text file to verify it. When I access the file direct in browser the function works fine, the user's id is correct but when the link is embedded in a player the returned id is null.

Comment: i also saw that PHPSESSID are different